# Get results from Spring call of Mongo MapReduce

Tags: spring, mongodb

I try to get the results of my mapReduce function on MongoDB directly after the call of my function in my Java Spring code :

```
MongoOperations mongoOperations = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new Mongo("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), "xxx"));
    MapReduceResults<Object> results = mongoOperations.mapReduce(
            "counters",
            mapFunctionCounters,
            reduceFunctionCounters,
            new MapReduceOptions().scopeVariables(scopeVariables).outputTypeInline(),
            Object.class);

    String jsonString = "";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(results);
        System.out.println("jsonString = " + jsonString);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Console result :

```
jsonString = {"rawResults":null,"outputCollection":null,"timing":{"mapTime":-1,"emitLoopTime":-1,"totalTime":576},"counts":{"inputCount":100287,"emitCount":7102,"outputCount":104}}
```

The mapReduce works well when I specify a collection output, but I don't understand how to get the results directly like with the `out: {inline: 1}` property used in the mongodb command.

Someone to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add the following class :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class ValueObject {
    private int id;
    private float value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ValueObject [id=" + id + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

Then change the way to display the result :

```
MapReduceResults<ValueObject> results = mongoOperations.mapReduce(
            "counters",
            mapFunctionCounters,
            reduceFunctionCounters,
            new MapReduceOptions().scopeVariables(scopeVariables).outputTypeInline(),
            ValueObject.class
            );

    for (ValueObject valueObject : results) {
        System.out.println(valueObject.getId());
    }
```